# How could I code this JavaScript function using functional programming paradigm?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

So basically I wrote this JS function to filter some posts content from a web forum.

```
    const postFilter = (vector) => {
        vector.forEach(e => {
            e.innerHTML.toLowerCase().match(/word1|word2|word3/g) ? e.style.display = 'none' : false;
        });
    }

    postFilter(document.getElementById('threadbits_forum_2').querySelectorAll('tr'));
```

Here are my questions:

Is the foreach method functional friendly? 
What about the regex? 
If I declare the regex as a constant it would still be a pure function?

Comment: Functional friendly: If respects functional paradigm. It refers to the regex. Pure functions are the ones where the return value depends only by their input.

Comment: Where do these come from? : `/word1|word2|word3/`

Comment: words are just an example as a constant value, they wont change in the program.

Comment: Ternary syntax is: `let/const/var x = (condition) ? (statement if true) : (statement if false)`. Also `forEach()` is not a functional programming friendly method especially in this case because it's used to change something outside the local scope of the function -- that is a side-effect.

Comment: Ty, now I see it clearly. So basically, using map/filter would be the correct way, right?

Comment: Mutating the DOM is the real issue with your function. Using `map` instead of `forEach` is just code hygiene in this case. You can see that your function is totally impure because it doesn't return anything, as there is nothing useful to be returned anyway. Functional GUI isn't trivial and I'd advice you to start with simpler FP concepts.

Comment: `forEach` relies on side effects and is therefore not functional. Adding to bob's comment, _reading_ the dom is an issue too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're conflating a few different things:

1. You want a list of tr elements
2. Filtered by regex match of their contents
3. Hidden

The third one is the problematic one as it's the one that is inherently non-functional (technically the first could as well, but we'll pretend the HTML can't change). In the functional paradigm you want to keep logic separate from the code that performs side-effects:

```
// Pull out the filtering logic into a pure (for Javascript) function
const filterElement = regex => elem => elem.innerHTML.match(regex);

// Pull the side-effect out into an impure function
const hide = elem => elem.style.display = 'none';

[ ...document.getElementById('threadbits_forum_2').querySelectorAll('tr') ]
  .filter(filterElement(/word1|word2|word3/gi)) // note the i flag
  .forEach(hide);
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I declare the regex as a constant it would still be a pure function?

Function which uses a constant is stil pure function. It's "just another function param". Think about constant equivalent to hidden function composition.

Pseudocode:

```
func a(c) {
    return func b(p) {
        return c + p
    }
}

const c1 = 5
a(c1)(6) = 11
a(c1)(7) = 12
...
```

The problem with your function is side effect on DOM. When you making changes in DOM other process can change also the same elements. It's not a functional approach. Read more how to deal with side effects on DOM with more functional approach.

Also, for your case use map instead of foreach.